# How do I profile maven tests on windows with JProfiler?

Tags: maven, jprofiler

I tried this

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <excludedGroups>com.my.test.IntegrationTest</excludedGroups>
      <argLine>-agentpath:C:\Program Files\jprofiler10\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849,nowait</argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <groups>com.my.test.IntegrationTest</groups>
      <argLine>-agentpath:C:\Program/ Files\jprofiler10\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849,nowait</argLine>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
```

which results in

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project my-util: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\bin\java" -agentpath:C:\Program Files\jprofiler10\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849,nowait -jar C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\my-util\target\surefire\surefirebooter6221605500745834451.jar C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\my-util\target\surefire\surefire4500791091163286071tmp C:\Users\xeno\IdeaProjects\my-util\target\surefire\surefire_07989865501871806496tmp"
```

bonus points if it auto starts recording in the UI when it become available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing

```
-agentpath:<path to jprofilerti.dll>=port=8849,nowait
```

will just load the profiling agent but not perform any recording. In your case, there is another problem because the JVM does not start up, most probably the space in `C:\Program Files` splits the argument into two arguments. I would recommend to install JProfiler into a path without spaces.

To record data and save a snapshot you have to configure **offline profiling**. The argument looks like this:

```
-agentpath:<path to jprofilerti.dll>=port=8849,offline,id=<session ID>
```

where the session ID is taken from the top-right corner of the "Application settings" tab in the session settings dialog. In that session, you configure a "JVM startup" trigger to start recording data and and a "JVM exit" trigger to save snapshot at the end.